# Literals don't work for preprocessor macros

Tags: c++, preprocessor, c++-chrono, user-defined-literals

Literals don't seem to interplay well with preprocessor macros. For example, I have this preprocessor definition `CONFIG_FADE_DELAY_MS` that I want to translate to `std::chrono::milliseconds`. But the `ms` literal needs to be written close up to it, the the compiler doesn't understand `ms` when there is a space in between them.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/c49d5Wc33)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <chrono>

#define CONFIG_FADE_DELAY_MS 5000

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main()
{
    // Works
    // const auto tp_now = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + 5000ms;
    // Doesn't work
    const auto tp_now = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + CONFIG_FADE_DELAY_MS ms;
}
```

I also tried to put parentheses around the preprocessor macro, and put the literal right behind it, but no luck.

Can this be done, or do I need to convert the macro manually?

```
std::chrono::milliseconds{CONFIG_FADE_DELAY_MS};
```

Comment: Why `const`? Try without it.

Comment: Can you not just do `#define CONFIG_FADE_DELAY_MS 5000ms`?

Comment: Does your 5000 need to be a preprocessor define? `static const auto CONFIG_FADE_DELAY = std::chrono::milliseconds{5000};`?

Comment: This is because of the extra space between the macro and `ms` qualifier. Maybe add `ms` into the macro as well as suggested, it would even make more sense since the macro name explicitly mention "MS".

Comment: @SirGuy even simpler: `static const auto CONFIG_FADE_DELAY = 5000ms;` Just have to move `using namespace std::chrono_literals;` above the declaration

Comment: @xihtyM I would do that but the value is pulled in by [kconfig](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/next/kbuild/kconfig-language.html) and thus it's not possible.

Comment: @glades `std::chrono::milliseconds(CONFIG_FADE_DELAY_MS)` will work. Or @Remy Lebeau's answer will work.

Comment: @xihtyM That's what I'm settling for :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the preprocessor's `##` token concatenation operator to join the `5000` and `ms` tokens, eg:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <chrono>

#define CONFIG_FADE_DELAY_MS 5000

#define CONCAT2(a, b) a ## b
#define CONCAT(a, b) CONCAT2(a, b)

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main()
{
    // Works, translates to:
    // const auto tp_now = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + 5000ms;
    const auto tp_now = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + CONCAT(CONFIG_FADE_DELAY_MS, ms);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/37GE76o6v)

The indirection of `CONCAT()` calling `CONCAT2()` is required in order for the preprocessor to first translate `CONFIG_FADE_DELAY_MS` to `5000` before then concatenating `ms` onto it. If you tried to use simply `#define CONCAT(a, b) a ## b` then the result would not be `5000ms` as expected but rather would be `CONFIG_FADE_DELAY_MSms` instead, which will obviously fail to compile since `CONFIG_FADE_DELAY_MSms` is not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be to use `std::chrono::milliseconds()`.

Here is an example:

```cc
#include <cstdio>
#include <chrono>

#define CONFIG_FADE_DELAY_MS 5000

int main()
{
    const auto tp_now = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::milliseconds(CONFIG_FADE_DELAY_MS);
}
```

This simply changes the number from an integer to `std::chrono::duration`, representing ms. It is also very explicit which is something I like.